# NSRegularExpression usage in iOS

Tags: iphone, regex, ipad

I'm looking for usage of regular expression in my user input string for presence of the following:
- atleast one character in uppercase
- atleast one numberic character
- atleast 8 characters wide.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (probably ascii only):

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}
```

or the Unicode variant (which, [according the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html), should be supported):

```
(?=.*\p{Lu})(?=.*\p{Nd}).{8,}
```

Meaning:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])  # an upper case, anywhere in the string (or \p{Lu})
(?=.*[0-9])  # a digit, anywhere in the string      (or \p{Nd})
.{8,}        # 8 or more chars
```

Comment: Hi Bart, this was the exact regular expression, I was looking for. Thanks.